# Sending a file using Log4j to QRadar DSM

Tags: java, log4j

I have just configured an Akamai Kona CEF Connector.
I can see my logs on the server as JSON format files.
I am trying to send these logs to a QRadar DSM.

Can I use simple sockets to send logs files already existing on my server to QRadar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use syslog,rsyslog protocol to getlog from server.

I hope tis information will help you pbout this problem.